# Delayed job "Event 'success' cannot transition from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have integrated delayed job to run Jenkins build from background. So for every build I am using **`AASM`** gem to update my status. Once every build completed I am getting error from my delayed job as `"Event 'success' cannot transition from 'success'` I am not able to find because of why it is happening.

I am calling my job from my **`approver_controller.rb`**

```
@build_request.delay(attempts: 1).run_batch
```

In build_request model I have my job method to execute Jenkins batch

```
class BuildRequest < ApplicationRecord
    include AASM
     aasm :column => :build_state do
        state :pending, initial: true
        state :onhold
        state :release
        state :approved
        state :rejected
        state :success
        state :failed

        event :approve do
            transitions from: [:pending], to: :approved
        end

        event :onhold do
            transitions from: [:pending], to: :onhold
        end

        event :release do
            transitions from: [:onhold], to: :pending
        end

        event :reject do
            transitions from: [:pending], to: :rejected
        end

        event :success do
            transitions from: [:approved], to: :success
        end

        event :fail do
            transitions from: [:approved], to: :failed
        end
    end

    def run_batch
            if self.approved?   
                file_name = "#{self.project_job_name}_#{self.id}.txt"
                new_file = File.open(file_name, "w+")
                new_file.puts self.project.job_name + "\r"
                new_file.puts input_path(self)
                new_file.close
                FileUtils.mv(Rails.root.join(file_name), Rails.root.join('public'))
                Net::SCP.start(ENV["IP_ADDRESSS"], ENV["USER_NAME"], :password => ENV["PASSWORD"]) do |scp|
                # asynchronous upload; call returns immediately and requires SSH
                # event loop to run
                    channel = scp.upload(Rails.root.join('public', file_name).to_s, jenkins_build_path)
                    channel.wait
                end
                Net::SSH.start(ENV["IP_ADDRESSS"], ENV["USER_NAME"], :password => ENV["PASSWORD"]) do |ssh|
                    output = ssh.exec!("file_path" " file_name")
                    # start building job 
                    build_status = ApplicationController.helpers.jenkins_client.job.build(self.project_job_name)
                    build_status == "201" ? self.success : self.failed
                end
            end
        end
```

Comment: Provide code where `AASM` is used. The first reason - `success` is initial state, so when you do `aasm_instance.success`, it causes illegal transition from `success` state to same one.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk I have updated my question with AASM.

Comment: Show please `ApplicationController.helpers.jenkins_client.job.build` source

Comment: This is my jenkins_client  def jenkins_client
    @client = JenkinsApi::Client.new(:server_ip => ENV["IP_ADDRESSS"], :username => ENV["JENKINS_USERNAME"], :password => ENV["JENKINS_PASSWORD"])
  end

Comment: I need `build` method source

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk build method is from Jenkins gem.

Comment: Try to rename `state :success` to `state :succeed` and change corresponding transitions' `to:`

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk I have moved my entire code to separate file now it is working fine. Thanks for your kind support.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and it took me some time to figure out:

DelayedJob [automatically adds](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#hooks) a `success` method to your model and will run it when the job is complete. That can conflict with the state management you're doing with AASM, causing it (for example) to be in a success state (via your code) and then having Delayed Job inadvertently trying to transition it to a success state again.